# serve public static files with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I struggle to get webpack configured as I want it to be.
I run my dev-server on **localhost:8080** and want to serve my app through **localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js** and that is what I get with this webpack.config.js file I've attached below. in my file structure i've alse attached I want to serve also the other files located in **dist/static** as static files, so **localhost:8080/static/css/style.css** will be serving this **dist/static/css/style.css** file for example.

it is probably something wrong i did in the config file, and i'm not that familiar with webpack so i don't know if im asking the question so you can understand.

My directory tree is:

```
client
  -- /dist
    -- /templates
      -- /admin
        -- index.html
    -- /static
      -- /css
        -- style.css
      -- /js
  -- /node_modules
  -- /src
  -- /test
  -- package.json
  -- webpack.config.json
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var plugins = [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css', {
        allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    })
];

var cssLoader = {};

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production'){
    plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    );

    cssLoader = {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
    };

} else {

    cssLoader = {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
            'style?sourceMap',
            'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        ]
    }

}

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['babel']
            },
            cssLoader
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/static',
        publicPath: '/static/js',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist/templates/admin',
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: plugins
};
```

dist/templates/admin/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <link href="static/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="static/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks guys :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Problem

The origin of the problem is that the WebpackDevServer **only serves from one folder**. The folder that you should be serving from is the folder containing the index.html, which is what you're correctly doing.

So far you're serving *only* the content of `./dist/templates/admin`, therefore when you look for files in other directories you get a 404. The only exception here is your bundle, because you're setting a `publicPath` that makes any request to the route `/static/js` be redirected to your output, which is stored in memory.

You would need the WebpackDevServer to be able to serve from other folders. In your specific case, you need to serve also from `./dist/static/css` when you request the path `/static/css`.

### Solution

You need to set some middlewares in your WebpackDevServer. You can do so as described in the [documentation of `devServer.setup`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-setup). To do so, I suggest you use [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static), as you're probably already using Express.

You need to require Express:

```
const express = require('express')
```

And then, just modify the `devServer` as follows:

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: './dist/templates/admin',
  hot: true,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  setup (app) {
    app.use('/static/css/',
      express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'static', 'css')));
    /* Using this commented code will break the HMR, see edit
    app.use('/static/js/',
      express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'static', 'js')));
    */
    
    // in general
    app.use('/public/route/',
      express.static('/your/local/path'));
  }
}
```

This way your devs and build paths stay the same, and the WebpackDevServer serves the static files you need, at the routes you need.

### Edit

I just discovered that the code above breaks the Hot Module Replacement. The reason is that the middleware in the setup is handling `/static/js/`, so the bundle is served from the file system instead of memory.

To keep fetching the bundle from memory define a `publicPath` in the `output` property, and don't handle it from a custom middleware inside `devServer.setup`.

```
module.exports = {
  
  output: {
    path: ...,
    filename: ...,
    publicPath: '/static/js/'
  },
  
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist/templates/admin',
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    setup (app) {
      app.use('/static/css/',
        express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'static', 'css')));
    }
  },

  // other properties: entry, module, etc.
}
```

Comment: I've tried a few versions of this mate but can't seem to get it going, if you're able to checkout my question for some help, that'd be great, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054824/webpack-middleware-with-jekyll-setup-for-context-path

Answer (score 2):

You are serving the app on port 8080. In your webpack config I see that you set content base dist/template/Admin but I don't see that folder any where. When you set content base it will serve Admin.html from that folder and if you have declared dependencies in that file it will load from you. [You can take a look at this seed](http://github.com/jorawarsingh/angular2-webpack-seed/config) to learn more about it.

Comment: you are right i forgot to include this dir. the admin/index.html is served as expected in localhost:8080/ and the static/js/bundle.js is served as expected but statc/css/style.css is 404. ill try to look at the resource youve attached. ive edited the question

Comment: oh sorry, added html file that importing css via regular link tag, just static file with relative path.

Comment: can you see if file being loaded in browser?

Comment: i would try to change contentbase to only dist and later just navigate to template/admin.html using contentbase will serve the static file from current directory.

Comment: Thanks man, the thing is that I want to keep order in my directory structure and store all HTML templates in one dir, but serve the admin/index.html in root of localhost. I'll try to 0lay a little bit with the contentbase. Thanks aga8n

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121487/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-dima-gimburg).

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, and it make sense in a way, webpack-dev-server is not supposed to be used as a backend to load static files such as CSS or other static JS when you are running another server aside. when you set the **contentBase** key to a specific directory, the documentation says that you have to make there an **index.html** file and you can serve files base on this directory.

If you want to serve static files from other dir and you have another server doing it running side by side with webpack-dev-server, please pay attention to [this section of the documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server#combining-with-an-existing-server).

What I did is run webpack-dev-server on **localhost:8080** and my backend server on **localhost:3000** and my backend server serves the **admin/index.html** from the root rout of it, on **localhost:3000/**, and in the html file itself changed the import of the bundle.js to be absolute path **`<script  src="http://localhost:8080/static/js/bundle.js"></script>`**.

Hot reload now works fine, and now i could also remove the **contentBase** param off of my webpack config file.

**Important:**

1. now to run the webpack like we want and make hot reload really work, just add *--inline* when you are running it, something like: `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --hot --config ./webpack.config.js --inline`
2. you can also use the iframe mode, but i didn't dived into it.
3. still got an issue that when building the project i have to manually remove the absolute path, that's annoying. looking how to solve it automatically now.

Comment: Check out my solution. You don't need to be changing the paths in development or production.