# Webpack middleware with Jekyll setup for context path

Tags: webpack, jekyll

I have a site hosted on github pages using Jekyll.

Essentially all I want to get Webpack server to load up :

http://localhost:8080/project/ - with the added feature being /project/ to make all my urls continue to work locally.

More on Jekyll setup:

To get all the url's working on github pages you have to set the base url:
baseurl: "/project/" then when you reference a url you use:

`<a href="{{ "page-1/" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">`

which would output to

```
<a href="/project/page-1/">
```

I want to replicate this url structure with webpack middleware.

Firstly I set the webpack dev server to look at the built Jekyll site:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: '_site/', //disk location
    watchContentBase: true
},
```

Then to make sure the files are served from /project/ I have added:

```
output: {
    filename: 'js/app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, ''),
},
```

I don't have Webpack building any html with HtmlWebpackPlugin, as that's what Jekyll is doing, so HTML webpack is not an option. Maybe some kind of express static server?

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything :(

```
const express = require('express');
setup(app){
    app.use('_site/', express.static('/project/'));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a repository where I can get more context?

Comment: Sorry I've got nothing hosted but it's pretty much just a Webpack starter kit (from the guide docs) with simple src and dist and Jekyll starter kit. The main part of my question is still the /project/. So for example, if I had the most basic setup like the web-pack guide walks you through, how can still achieve the the extra subpath in the web-pack-dev-server. Alot of uses suggest the express server, but I can't get it working.

Comment: @dgrcode Sorry the only other thing I forgot to mention is that it had to be served statically (no webpack memory instance) since I am using Jekyll to build the html files.